# Comparisons with Scala's Numeric types?

Tags: scala, math, numeric

How can one create a class which does math **and** comparisons on any numeric type in Scala?

One obvious approach:

```
import math.Numeric.Implicits._

class Ops[T : Numeric] {
    def add(a: T, b: T) = a + b
    def gt(a: T, b: T) = a > b
}
```

Earns me this...

```
Ops.scala:7: value > is not a member of type parameter T
```

Hmmm... we can do math with numeric types, but we can't compare them?

So let's also say that `T` is `Ordered[T]`...

```
class Ops[T <: Ordered[T] : Numeric] {
    def add(a: T, b: T) = a + b
    def gt(a: T, b: T) = a > b
}
```

That compiles.  But try to use it?

```
new Ops[Int].gt(1, 2)
```

And I get...

```
Ops.scala:13: type arguments [Int] do not conform to class Ops's type parameter bounds [T <: Ordered[T]]
```

So how can I operate on some type which is both ordered and numeric?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
scala> import Ordering.Implicits._
import Ordering.Implicits._

scala> import Numeric.Implicits._
import Numeric.Implicits._

scala> class Ops[T : Numeric] {
     |   def add(a: T, b: T) = a + b
     |   def gt(a: T, b: T) = a > b
     | }
defined class Ops

scala> new Ops[Int].gt(12, 34)
res302: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of that kind of global import in contrast to the local import `numeric.mkXXXOps`. Will use that.

Comment: `Numeric` extends `Ordering`, so asking for an `Ordering` context bounds is redundant! `T : Numeric` suffices.

Comment: @Sciss Good point! Was it me who said that one should have a _close_ look at the API?! Haven't looked close enough to see `Numeric <: Ordering`...

Comment: I was guessing that numeric had to be ordered in some way (which is why  I was so puzzled in my remark below).  I also wasn't aware of the ordering implicits.  (Just getting started.)

Answer (score 4):

You have to import `mkNumericOps` and/or `mkOrderingOps`:

```
val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
```

or

```
class Ops[T](implicit num: Numeric[T])
```

then:

```
import num.{mkNumericOps,mkOrderingOps}
```

Now you can compare and calc with them.
Perhaps that hels you for the first part of your question.

By the way: Ordered and Numeric works like that:

```
class Ops[T: Ordered: Numeric]
```

Comment: That would be `T : Ordering : Numeric` (or `T <: Ordered : Numeric` or `T <% Ordered : Numeric`)

Comment: @Tim I had your problem myself and thought there has to be a way not that clumsy calling `gt`. So I had a look at the API and there was this mysterious `mkOrderingOps`... Always have a close look at the API!

Comment: It should be said that you do not need `T` to be `Ordered` for this to work. So it suffices to have `T : Numeric`. As didierd points out, `Ordered` would be used as a view bound here (`T <% Ordered`) and doesn't make sense as a context bound. Performance-wise, using an `Ordering` with `Ordering.Implicits._` should be the better choice, as with `Ordered` you will have your values being boxed unnecessarily.

Comment: Yeah, I also took a stab at using `gt`, but could even get *that* working.  As I remark below, I'm just getting up to speed, and am still a little confused as to why the `import num.{mkNumericOps,mkOrderingOps}` works.  That how does that import *infix* operators on *other* variables?

Comment: @Tim: `mkNumericOps` is an implicit conversion from type `N` to type `Op` (where `N` is some `Numeric` type). This class `Op` holds the infix numeric operators. In other words, `a + b` in your code desugars to `mkNumericOps(a).+(b)`.

Comment: @Tim: Check this [source](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/math/Numeric.scala#L207).